# Apply transition for single pseudoclass

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions, css-animations

I want a transition on my button which should only be applied on `hover` but not on other pseudoclasses.

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

button:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Nice Button!</button>
```

So in this case I want it the transition from green to blue on `hover` but not from blue to red when `active`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: or set `transition:none` on the `:active` state

Comment: @PlantTheldea that makes the hover transition not easing out

Comment: So when the button is active you still want it to be red, just without the CSS transition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to admit that your question is challenging !

My proposed solution:

```
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    transition: background-color 2s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

button:active {
/*    background-color: red; */
    -webkit-animation: activate 0s 0s forwards;
    animation: activate 0s 0s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes activate {
    0% {background-color: green;}
   100% {background-color: red;}
}

@keyframes activate {
    0% {background-color: green;}
   100% {background-color: red;}
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cymtqxx9/)

The problem is that the base state is shared beteen the back transition from the hover and the activer pseudo classes, so I don'tthink this can be solved using only transitions.

The trick is not to change the color in the active state, it is still green *inside*, but it looks red :-)

Answer (score 5):

Set `transition: none;` on `:active` pseudo class + if you don't want a transition on mouseup, you can add

```
button:focus {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: none;
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

button:focus:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: none;
}
button:active:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Nice Button!</button>
```

Comment: but it has a transition on mouseup then

Comment: this is a nice workaround but it needs to lose focus to turn back to green and therefore not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @DonJuwe Just realised that the the transition doesn't work if you rehover the button...